# How do i add hover only inside the border when i made it elliptical

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have made a button elliptical using border and i want to add hover which should change background only inside the border, how do i do it ?

```
<li className="headerRightLink">
   <button className="tryQuoraButton">Try Quora+</button>
</li>

.headerRightLink {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: space-between;
 font-size: 30px;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.headerRightLink:hover {
 background-color: rgb(241, 238, 238);
}

.tryQuoraButton {
 padding: 5px;
 width: 90px;
 height: 30px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: white;
 -webkit-border-radius: 40px/30px;
 -moz-border-radius: 40px/30px;
 border: 0.5px solid rgb(226, 217, 217);
 border-radius: 40px/35px;
 border-style: solid;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-weight: 700;
 color: gray;
} 
.tryQuoraButton:hover {
 border-radius: 40px/35px;
 background-color: rgb(241, 238, 238);
}
```

[image]

I want this image round

```css
.tryQuoraButton {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 90px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-border-radius: 40px/30px;
  -moz-border-radius: 40px/30px;
  border: 0.5px solid rgb(226, 217, 217);
  border-radius: 40px/35px;
  border-style: solid;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: gray;
}

.tryQuoraButton:hover {
  border-radius: 40px/35px;
  background-color: rgb(241, 238, 238);
}
```

```html
<li class="headerRightLink">
  <button class="tryQuoraButton">Try Quora+</button>
</li>
```

Comment: I've added a snippet to your question, seems like it works fine

Comment: Yes , i think , my previous classes was making things wrong

Comment: Remove the `.headerRightLink:hover` rule which sets the border of the container.